# How do I get Rails 3.1 with ElasticSearch & Tire working on Heroku Cedar Stack?

Tags: elasticsearch, heroku, tire, cedar, bonsai-elasticsearch

I'm having trouble getting Tire working using ElasticSearch with the Bonsai addon on the Heroku Cedar stack. It keeps crashing my app and when I check the Heroku logs (i.e. run `heroku logs` in Terminal), I `Errno::ECONNREFUSED (Connection refused - connect(2))`.

The setup works fine on my localhost. I've been all through the Elastic search resources and haven't found a fix yet.

Can anyone provide some assistance or guidance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally found it... Through an obscure link on the Heroku Bonsai helps. I did this and it worked: [Configuring Tire to use the Bonsai ElasticSearch Heroku add-on](https://gist.github.com/2041121)

Here's a little more clarification on what I did to fix it.. In `config/initializers/bonsai.rb`:

```
  if ENV['BONSAI_INDEX_URL']
   Tire.configure do
    url "http://index.bonsai.io"
   end
   BONSAI_INDEX_NAME = ENV['BONSAI_INDEX_URL'][/[^\/]+$/]
  else
    app_name = Rails.application.class.parent_name.underscore.dasherize
    app_env = Rails.env
    BONSAI_INDEX_NAME = "#{app_name}-#{app_env}"
  end
```

Comment: What did you put in the ELASTICSEARCH_URL? the Full access link to the API?

Comment: I followed ernesto-jimenez's comment on the link in my answer... I'll revise my answer to include the code.

Comment: SHUMAcupcake: Did that get you what you need?

Comment: No really, but found out what was wrong. I forget to index it in production mode. thanks anyway dude, you are awesome!